# Align Bootstrap 3 Navbar-right and include search box also right-aligned

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

I'm using bootstrap 3 to build a site and I am having the following problem:

The site design I am working from has a right-aligned navigation that should include a search bar following the final link. Here's a visual:https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpPkZ.jpg

I can only seem to make this work if I keep the navigation left aligned after the logo. I can't get the navigation AND the search bar to be in a nice right-aligned line.

I would like to have it look much the same as I have it now, but with that search bar on the other side.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#">BRAND</a>
        </div><!-- / .navbar-header--> 
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
          <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                </div>
          </div>
            </form>
          </div>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div><!-- /. container-->
</div> <!-- /. navbar-->
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to wrap with a div to float right.

Simply use the class names already available, the clue is in the markup `.navbar-left` and `.navbar-right`. Use these to float an element left or right within the Navbar and avoid 'divitis'.

You will need to swap the links and search around as we are floating.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgmilcher/o6ucyh6v/)

There is also `.pull-left` and `.pull-right` that you can use elsewhere on the page for similar floating requirements.

Answer (score 3):

I closed the ul tag after the search-form div. Works perfect.

link

link two

link three

about

```
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
      <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
      </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the newest sample on Bootstrap official site to do the test and I think it can be done by a few css rule. Wrap the elements which you want to be right-aligned and set the wrapper's position and right. See the sample.

```
#right
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
}

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>


    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

        <div id="right">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
            </div>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cyfloel0516/CvDTz/)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem** : Align search box and button

**Solution** : Below code was part of ruby html.erb file.

```
<!-- Search form -->
  <%= form_tag "", url: students_path, class:"form-inline my-2 my-lg-0", role: "search", method: :get do %>
      <div class="input-group">        
        <%= text_field_tag :search, @search_term, class: "form-control mr-sm-2", placeholder: "Search" %>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </div>
  <% end %>
  <!-- Search form -->
```

[image]

**Note**: input-group solved my problem.